# How to add placeholder image to ion-slides in ionic 3 app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ion-slides

I want to add placeholder image to my ion-slider before my images are loaded dynamically.
Here is my code:

HTML

```html
<div *ngIf="service?.banners" class="home-banners">
        <ion-slides  pager="true"  spaceBetween="5" loop="true" autoplay="3900">
            <ion-slide *ngFor='let value of service.banners'>
                
                 <img src="{{value}}"> 
                </ion-slide>
        </ion-slides>
    </div>
```

SCSS

```
.home-banners {
    ion-slides {

        height: 50%; 
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
         padding-top: 5px;

    }
}
```

Comment: is "value" in your case a URL to the proper image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pursue lazy loading approach you could do something like this below:

- add a div wrapper and make its background grey (e.g. skeleton UI) or
  point it to URL (i used external but you can use an img from local assets)
- use attribute binding condition to only set src of actual img if it
  is active slide or +1 index from it (you can alter conditions you need here)
- on load of actual image - set a flag in your data model to keep src
  intact if the image was already loaded

html template:

```
<ion-content>
  <div>
    <ion-slides #sliders pager="true" spaceBetween="5">
      <ion-slide *ngFor='let imgItem of images; index as i;'>
        <div class="lazySlide">
          <img class="lazyImage" [src]="(sliders.getActiveIndex() == i || sliders.getActiveIndex() == i-1) || imgItem.loaded? imgItem.source:''" (load)="imgItem.loaded=true">
        </div>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Component code example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  images: Array<{ loaded: boolean, source: string}> = [
    {
      loaded: false,
      source: "https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/nature"
    },
    {
      loaded: false,
      source: "https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/people"
    },
    {
      loaded: false,
      source: "https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/tech"
    },
    {
      loaded: false,
      source: "https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/architecture"
    },
    {
      loaded: false,
      source: "https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/animals"
    }
  ]

  constructor(
  ) {
  }

}
```

scss:

```
page-home {
    .lazyImage {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .lazySlide {
        background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I used your code , Image slider was shown on the full page.

Comment: Of course, because css is done this way, you can style it and tune the code based on your use case. Your question doesn’t explain how in the end it should look hence i went generic about it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Simply fix the height of the div using style="height:200px"

and then in the css file simply add your placeholder image.
So when the image will be fully loaded, it would be shown over the background image and would hide it.